# Binding and Unbinding of a class that extends a JibX auto-generated class

Tags: java, jibx

I have a class called ObjectClass that was auto-generated by JibX from a .xsd file. To prevent class name issues this class has been relegated to its own package, such as

com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass

This class binds and unbinds as intended.

I would like to create an empty class that extends the above class, and I am wondering will the new class bind and unbind correctly using the original ObjectClass binding? Or must I attempt to make a unique binding for this new extension?

The new class looks similar to this

```
public class deviceGetCommandsResponse extends 
com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass
{
   /// This is empty
}
```

This intention of this is to make casting these objects easier/less hassle for third party developers by providing unique names.

So instead of

```
(com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass) SomeReturnFromAMethod
```

they can use

```
(deviceGetCommandsResponse) SomeReturnFromAMethod;
```

and have all the same functionality.

In broader terms how would I go about making an Adapter Pattern for JibX generated classes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, JiBX will work fine in an extended class.

Before you do this, I would consider these options:

First, the default package name is the namespace URL location and the default class name is the top-level element which is an excellent choice for most bindings.

For example, If my schema definition's is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.jibx.org/sampleschema/person" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.jibx.org/sampleschema/person">
<xs:element name="person">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The generated class would be:

```
package org.jibx.sampleschema.person;
public class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
```

Your code would read:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Don");
```

This is pretty logical and pretty clean. It is very useful to have a globally unique class name, especially if you are using a public schema definition. Releasing your bindings as open source will save some time for others using the same schema.

If the default is not acceptable, changing a package and/or class name is pretty easy by setting the JiBX configuration.

I hope this helps!

Don Corley
JiBX Contributor